# How to use a static constant in a class .h file to define the length of an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, constants, header-files

I have several constraints of coding rules, and I'm searching a solution to make this work. In a .h file :

```
namespace myNamespace
{
    class MyClass
    {
        protected:
            MyArrayType myArray[10];
    };
}
```

I have the following constraints :

- I must declare the 10 value in a constant attribute inside this class (in .h or .cpp), initialized by the call of a constructor "(...)".
- I must declare the attributes of this class in this visibility order : public, protected, private.
- I must code in C++03

I've tried to make this :

```
namespace myNamespace
{
    class MyClass
    {
        protected:
            static const int TEN(10);
            MyArrayType myArray[TEN];
    };
}
```

But I have the following compilation error on the line of the declaration of `TEN`:

> error: expected identifier before numeric constant

Define the `TEN` constant in protected instead of private is due to the second constraint listed above.

Any idea of a possible solution please ?

Thank you.

Best regards.

Comment: as a side note, calling it `TEN` will leave you very confused when you need to change it to 15.  I'd suggest calling it `ArraySize` or something of that ilk

Comment: I know, it is just an example... :p

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in the *in-class* initializer, use *braces* (`{}`) instead of *parenthesis* (`()`):

```
static const int TEN{10};
```

or `=`:

```
static const int TEN = 10;
```

Comment: In C++11, you might also want to use `constexpr` to explicitly demonstrate a compile-time constant.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to use {} neither =, there is another coding rule which forces to call explicitly the constructors to initialize the objects, and another which forces to use C++03.

Comment: @Madvin if that's the coding rule, word for word; 'int' isn't an object; and using `= 10` is much nicer than a #define

Comment: @UKMonkey : the use of int is just for the example. We don't use explicitly the primitive types in the code, but typedefs. We use Logiscope to check the violations of the rules, and Logiscope considers the typedefs as objects. But even if we use the primitive types, we must init their value by the notation ( ).

Comment: @Madvin a coding style that says you have to do something the language can't support should be binned.  I would suggest that if there are limitations to what you can do, you state that in your question, rather than let people answer and then correct it since it wastes everyone's time; (though mostly yours).

Comment: @UKMonkey : It's not easy to give you all the limitations we have... there are 270 coding rules to respect. I can't give you all of them of course...

Comment: So it seems it is impossible with all these constraints, so the solution has been to relax the coding rule of the numeric constant in the array declaration, and so I have deleted the constant attribute. Like this :

`namespace myNamespace
{
    class MyClass
    {
        protected:
            MyArrayType myArray[10]; // %RELAX<const> impossible to easily extract in a constant attribute the size of an array attribute.
    };
}`